# Nested randomization/permutation test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, permutation-test

Suppose I have data from an experiment performed at 2 different locations.  Site 1 has 10 participants and site 2 has 100.  I want to assess if certain response/dependent variables differ by site before the experiment intervention by doing a simple test of the means.  However, because of the not insignificant difference in sample sizes between the sites, I do not think a t-test of the means with n=10 versus n=100 is fair, because most likely the site with the smaller sample will have greater variability (among other differences).

So.  I think a permutation/randomization test is more appropriate here.  What I have in mind is to 1st randomly draw a sample of size 10 from site 2 (the one with 100 participants).  Then do a permutation test with the original n=10 from site 1 and the sub-sampled n=10 from site 2 and get a p-value.  Then I would repeat the sub-sampling from site 2 (with n=100) thousands of times and repeat the permutation test.  This leads me to a few questions.

1. Am I thinking about how to solve this problem in an appropriate manner?
2. If the setup is reasonable, does this nested permutation make sense?
3. If the nested permutation makes sense, I would end up with a distribution of p-values. I am not sure how to translate this into a decision, whether there are site differences or not.

Comment: There is nothing inappropriate about doing a $t$-test with unequal sample sizes.